# Vue server table checkbox not reactive

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have vue server table with a templated checkbox. Outside I have a property called selectAllFlag that gets set according to data recived from api and data selected in table. The problem occurs that the checkbox inside the server table does not get checked when the flag gets set to true vice versa.

```html
 <v-server-table
      :columns="columns"
      :options="GridOptions"
      ref="stickersTable"
      @row-click="onRowClick"
    >
      <div slot="h__checkbox">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          class="cb__input"
          :checked="getSelectAllFlag"
          @click="toggleSelectAll($event.target.checked)"
        />
                 .
                 .
                 .
      </div>
<v-server-table>
```

And that is how I define it inside class

```js
export default class Stickers extends Vue {
  public selectAllFlag: boolean = false;

  get getSelectAllFlag() {
    return this.selectAllFlag;
  }
```

Edit:
Changed binding to v-model and the problem persists

```
 <input
      type="checkbox"
      class="cb__input"
      v-model="selectAllFlag"
      @click="toggleSelectAll($event.target.checked)"
    />
```

Comment: You should be using v-model on your checkbox to bind it with selectAllFlag